# Double printers in settings menu

Tags: 16.04, settings

After installing updates on Ubuntu 16.04 I ended up with double entry for printers in settings menu.

Is there a way to remove one of them? I see no point in having it there twice.

[image: Printers show up twice]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching `unity-control-center` instead of `gnome-control-center` solved it